# Edward's mind reading of James

Tags: twilight

In Twilight, When Edward, Rosalie and Carlisle are running in the forest to spread Bella's scent, when James decides to change course, how does Edward know? He says he can read the mind only at a certain distance, and Alice is in Phoenix. How then was Edward able to know the tracker's change of mind? It seemed as if he had been able to read his mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edward does NOT know what James is planning. He goes to Phoenix to get Bella. Before he gets there, James is already there, has contacted Bella, and convinced her to get away from the Cullens and go to the ballet studio. Since Alice and Jasper already know about the studio, they are able to find it and save Bella.